# How to solve error while trying to create new app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have tried to install this stuff for a week and been struggling since then

I tried this

```
cd /mnt/c

mkdir -p code
```

Then I tried creating the Rails app and setting up the database

```
rails new test_app -d postgresql

cd test_app

rails db:create
```

Then I get this error

```
warning Integrity check: Top level patterns don't match
error Integrity check failed
error Found 1 errors.

========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================


To disable this check, please change `check_yarn_integrity`
to `false` in your webpacker config file (config/webpacker.yml).


yarn check v1.22.5
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check for documentation about this command.
```

Another times I get the error

```
/var/postgres: can't connect to database"
```

This is my `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  host: localhost
  password: 7532
  port: 5433
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test_app_development
```

Please help, I'm a noob here who doesn't know what he's doing haha

Comment: Way too little information. We don't even know your operating system. I think you need some basic training, and Q&A won't fit the bill.

Comment: Windows 10. The terminal is Ubuntu